# Determine every polynomial with real coefficients such that $P(P(x))=[P(x)]^k$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

I have doubts wrt my solution for the following problem. Determine every polynomial with real coefficients such that $P(P(x))=[P(x)]^k$

My guess is that $P(x)=x^k$. I started by saying let $r_n \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $P(r_n)=n$. Hence, $P(P(r_n))=P(r_n)^k$ implies $P(n)=n^k$. Since $P(n)=x^k$ for $x\in \mathbb{Z}$, we have $P(n)\equiv x^k$

My main point of concern is that I went from the Reals to Complex field to obtain $r_n$, how legitimate is this approach?

Comment: Why is that $P(x)$ will necessarily take all integer values? For example, $P(x) \equiv 0$ doesn't take all integer values and yet is a solution to the given functional equation.

Comment: My thought was that I was solving the roots of $Q_n(x)=P(x)-n=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a similar approach, without needing complex numbers, only that the range of $P$ is infinite.

If $P(x)$ is not constant, then $P(y)-y^k$ has infinitely many roots, name when $y$ is in the range of $P.$

So $P(x)-x^k$ must be the zero polynomial.

Then you also have two or three constant polynomial options for $P,$ when $k$ is even or odd, respectively.

Comment: My thoughts exactly! I wanted to be a bit more explicit with $r_n$, did I make a mistake on that end? Oh you’re right I should have said $0$ and $1$ work as well

Comment: Also $-1$ if $k$ is odd.

Comment: Yes, your answer works, but it needlessly references the complex roots. You just need that the image of $P$ is infinite.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks. Updated answer.

Comment: Also we were not told that $k$ is a nonnegative integer.  If it is not, only the constant solutions are possible.